# Migrate existing html template to meteor and iron router

Tags: html, meteor, iron-router

New to meteor and iron router. Hope can get some help.

I am trying to use the following template for a meteor application:
https://shapebootstrap.net/item/1524991-oxygen-free-bootstrap-one-page-theme

However, i am stuck getting all the file structure in the correct way when combine with iron router.

Below are my files structure:
Inside JS:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('Main');
});
```

All the css inside "/client/css"

font, images and js under "/public"

in the main.html, if i did not add the below:
at the top

```
<template name="main">
```

at the bottom

```
</template>
```

it work fine. But this kind of defeat the purpose of iron router because all the pages will load this html first. If i add the 2 tags above, seem like the js at the bottom of the html not loaded properly or not in proper sequence:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.inview.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mousescroll.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Any idea how should i fix this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add the scripts files, you have package to install from atmospherejs.com

Example: find twbs: bootstrap and it will auto install the bootstrap.min and other dependencies.

So similar for maps and jquery.

If you don't understand iron:router than check out example docs at atmospherejs and probably you will be able to fix it

You will be able to relate to iron router example after you see docs:
    Router.route('/', {
        name: 'home',
        template: 'home'
    });

Comment: Hi, i understand how to create routing using iron router, the part i don't understand is, before adding the template tag, the page load successfully, after adding the template tag, it failed. as for the script files, i prefer to keep them in public folder so that i can control the load seq in this way. anyway, what i try to archive is really basic, use the existing template, move it to meteor, add iron-router so that i can add multi page (login, register etc). but now i failed to even make the single html work with iron router.

Comment: You may try the way you want but I feel thats not the meteor way, though I maybe wrong!

Comment: i really don't think the issue is regarding how to add those dependency, i manage to dig a little further, now i guess the issue had to be with main.js. Maybe is the seq of loading or some things, it work if not inside the template tag, and not working when put it inside the template tag. really strange.